# How to prevent regular users accessing other users data and allow accessing others data if logged in user is an admin?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api, owin

I am developing Web APIs using ASP.net for an application. Currently working on implementing role-based user authentication. I am trying to understand how I could prevent authenticated users accessing others data.
One approach I am working on is:

> A unique key per record per user across all tables. So I could
> validate the request if it belongs to the requested user or not.  But
> how I could allow the operation if the requested user is an admin?

I could allow this by allowing different requests in the controller based on user validation. In this, I have to pass the user role to data access function to decide if the requested operation is allowed or not.

> (If a regular user -> only allowed his record updates (based on the
> unique key belongs to the user across all tables))
>
> (If an admin -> all operations are allowed)

Are there are any other smarter elegant methods?

I want to use ASP.net/C# existing libraries rather than implementing my own classes.

Comment: I think that makes sense. If data belongs to a user, their ID should be part of the record anyway and data should be got using `where userid = n`.

Comment: Thanks, I wonder how I could add admin functionality to the same API rather than writing new routines for admins.

Comment: Pretty broad question. You might have to narrow that down a bit and ask a new question. Do some research first.

Comment: So did some homework and lot of reading, I found that the right way to do this is by defining role-based user authentication. IT allows me to do all that I need with better security and accuracy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So did some homework and lot of reading, I found that the right way to do this is by defining role-based user authentication. It allowed me to do all that I need with better security and accuracy.
I used ASP.net authentication.